# Finding the derivative of arctan

Tags: calculus

y=arctan sqrt[(1+x)/(1-x)]

what i did:
let u= sqrt[(1+x)/(1-x)]
du=1/2 [(1-x)/(1+x)]^1/2 [{(1+x)(-1)-(1-x)}/(1+x)^2]dx

I solved this problem many times, but I don't get the right answer....

Comment: **Hint:** $~-1\le x\le1\quad=>\quad x=\cos2t,\quad1+\cos2t=2\cos^2t,\quad1-\cos2t=2\sin^2t$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x)=\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}$, so that $y=\arctan g(x)$

Using the chain rule and the quotient rule, we have
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{d(g(x))}\frac{d(g(x))}{dx}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1+x}{1-x}}\frac{1-x+1+x}{(1-x)^2}=\frac{1}{1-x}$$